# Script that splits traffic

Tags: javascript, redirect, traffic

I'm trying to create a javascript that sends people to different websites splitting the traffic. The idea is to split the traffic into 3 different websites. So 33% of the traffic goes to each website.
I have this.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
var now = new Date().getTime();  // time in milliseconds
if (now%99 == 0) {  // 20% of occasions
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

But i'm lost right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is... way off.  For starters, 33% and 20% are very different values.  But more importantly, `now % 99` is more like *1%*.

To split between three different actions, use `% 3`.  Something like this:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var split = now % 3;
if (split == 0) {
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
} else if (split == 1) {
  // something else
} else if (split == 2) {
  // something else
}
```